# Grouping | Aggregation in PostgresSql using Sequalize

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am migrating from MongoDB to PostgresSql and changing ORM from Mongoose to Sequelzie for Node.

I want to change my aggregate call written in Mongoose-Node using MongoDb to group all the posts under one date and calculate the total amount as well. Here is how it looks like and functions well:

```
Model.aggregate(
[
  {
    $match: searchObj
  },
  {
    $group : {
      _id : { year : { $substr : ["$creditedAt", 0, 4 ] }, month : { $substr : ["$creditedAt", 5, 2 ] }, day : { $substr : ["$creditedAt", 8, 2 ] } },
      amount: { $sum: "$amount" },
      earnings: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { "_id.day": -1, "_id.month": -1, "_id.year": -1 } },
  { $skip: options.skip },
  { $limit: options.limit },
]
```

);

Result:

```
{
 "_id": {
        "year": "2019",
        "month": "06",
        "day": "08"
        },
 "amount": 2500,
 "earnings": [
      {
   "_id": 1,
   "amount" 1500
},{
   "_id": 2,
   "amount" 1000
}
],
count: 2,
},
{
 "_id": {
        "year": "2019",
        "month": "06",
        "day": "07"
        },
 "amount": 2000,
 "earnings": [
      {
   "_id": 3,
   "amount" 1000
},{
   "_id": 4,
   "amount" 1000
}
],
count: 2,
}
```

Please help how I can write the same in Sequelzie-Node using PostgreSql.

Thanks!

-- V